# Html table attributes are lost after some posts

Tags: jsf

I'm experiencing a weird behavior with Payara 5 and JSF.
The problem is similar to the one [described here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6801231) whose solution I cannot read.

One xhtml page has the following structure:

```
 <h:form styleClass="jsfcrud_list_form" >
  <ui:include src="verySimple.xhtml" /> 
  <h:commandButton ... action="#{datatableController.applyFilter}" />
  <h:dataTable value="#{datatableController.items}" var="item" border="0" 
   cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" 
   rules="all" style="border:solid 1px;min-width: 600px" captionClass="caption4Table">
...
```

**applyFilter** simply adds an element. After pushing the button 2/3 times the datatable is rendered as , all attributes are lost.
If I copy the content of *verySimple.xhtml* instead of including it everything works fine.

In web.xml there are some *javax.faces* parameters I don't remember well, they come from years ago. Do you think they can explain this strange behavior ?

**UPDATE 1**

Currently I have difficulties migrating to Payara 6, cannot test with latest versionas requested.
Anyway I can provide a minimal working example.

```
@Named("datatableController")
@ViewScoped
public class DatatableController implements Serializable {

List<String> items = null;

@PostConstruct
protected void initData() {
   items = new ArrayList<String>();
   items.add("First");
   items.add("Second");

}

public List<String> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void applyFilter() {
    items.add("Another one");
}
}
```

Controller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">


<h:body>
       <div style="width:720px;margin: 0 auto">
        <h:form  >
            
            <ui:include src="Decorami.xhtml" /> 
               
            <h:commandButton  value="Filtra" 
                     action="#{datatableController.applyFilter}" />
            <br/><br/>  
           <h:dataTable value="#{datatableController.items}" 
  var="item" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rules="all" 
                         style="border:solid 1px;min-width: 600px">

                <f:facet name="caption">
                    <h:outputText value="Some sort of table"/>
                </f:facet>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Column 1"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    #{item.toString()}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Column 2"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="Second column"/>
                </h:column>
               
               
            </h:dataTable>   
        </h:form>
        </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The included file can be as simple as:

```
<ui:composition>
    Decorami 2   
</ui:composition>
```

After posting the form 2 times the table loses its attributes.
Executing a *get* the table displays correctly.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Payara 5 is old. You should be testing with latest version as well.

Comment: Ok, which JSF impl/version are you using then? This problem is clearly a bug in JSF impl/version being used and most possibly already fixed in a newer JSF impl/version.

Comment: I performed a fast test with  latest Payara 6 and the problem is not present. I cannot migrate in the short time, what can I try in the meantime, an alternative jsf library ?

Comment: You can upgrade the Payara-bundled Mojarra 2.2.x version by replacing the glassfish/modules/javax.faces.jar file with the latest available Mojarra 2.3.x version (using exactly same file name if possible). It's backwards compatible and has nearly all bugfixes already implemented.